# How do I use a ListProperty(users.user) in a djangoforms.ModelForm on Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, single-sign-on

I have been looking around a bit for info on how to do this. Essentially I have a Model:

```
class SharableUserAsset(db.Model):
  name = StringProperty()
  users = ListProperty(users.User)
```

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to associate users to this value where they are not authenticated, visa vi invite from contacts list etc.?
2. Is there a reasonable way to present a list control easily in a djangoforms.ModelForm?
3. Once a user logs in I want to be able to check if that user is in the list for any number of SharableUserAsset class "records", how do I do that?
4. Does user evaluate as a match to an email address or is there a way to look up a valid user against an email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a query, comparing a list property
>   to a value performs the test against
>   the list members: list_property =
>   value tests if the value appears
>   anywhere in the list

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ListProperty

So to find all the `SharableUserAsset`s associated with the current user just query like:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
assets = SharableUserAsset.gql("WHERE users = :1", user)
```

Here's [another reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#Lists) dealing with `ListProperty` objects.

An App Engine [`User`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html) object contains an email address, and the email address can be retireved using the `.email()` method.

Comment: Good answer to that part, but my question is also slightly about storing the user in a useful way as an invite, say from the contact list of a gmail account. Then when the user who was invited comes to the site logged in with that account associating the two. I suppose for me the problem is: while a user contains and email, an email is not a user.

Comment: Thats one of the reasons I don't use the Google user authentication.  I made my own, and just store email addresses.  Another reason I don't like it, is it takes you off site to a non branded page to log in.  But, a good thing about using Google's authentication, is they validate the user's email for you.

So I just skipped using User objects, and only store email strings with StringListProperty

Comment: Point taken, this is likely to be sufficient for now.